# Preventing multiple keypresses from RF remote

Tags: xorg, keyboard, remote-control

I needed to replace a Gyration remote control (which was for controlling MythTV) and it is no longer made.  So I got a Keyspan TSBX-2404.  It works in the sense that it communicates with the box (Fedora 15) but unlike the Gyration it sends multiple keypresses whenever I hit a button.  For example, in xev if I press a button it will give 4-6 entries.  It is controlling MythTV this way too--for example hitting the right arrow key will scroll two stops in a horizontal list rather than one.  This is not acceptable, and I am wondering if there is some way to deal with it.  For example, is there a setting in X that will filter out multiple keypresses that happen within a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is turn on [BounceKeys](http://accessibility.linuxfoundation.org/a11yspecs/kbd/kafs.html#def-bouncekeys).  I've never needed that, and I'm not quite sure how you turn it on in Fedora 15, but maybe that will give you something to search for.